# Proof Check: Let $X$ be a normed space. Then ball $X^*$ (closed unit ball of $X^*$) is weak-star metrizable if and only if $X$ is separable.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I just began to learn Analysis by myself. Can someone please help me check my proof to see any errors in math, logic and English. Thank you so much!!

> **Fact 1:** Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space and let $(Y,d_Y)$ be a subspace of $(X,d)$. Then $(Y,d_Y)$ is separable.
>
> **Fact 2:** Let $(X,T_X)$ and $(Y,T_Y)$ be topological spaces such that $Y$ is Hausdorff, let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$, and let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous functionals such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.
>
> **Fact 3:** Let $(X,T_X)$ a compact topological space, let $(Y,T_Y)$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a bijective continuous functional. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.
>
> **Fact 4:** Let $X$ be a normed space and let $A$ be a non-empty countable subset of $X$. Then $\overline{\operatorname{span}}(A)$ is separable.

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be a normed space. Then ball $X^*$ (closed unit ball of $X^*$) is weak-star metrizable if and only if $X$ is separable.

**Proof**: Suppose $X$ is separable. Then by Fact 1, ball $X$ is separable. Thus there exists a countable dense subset $\{x_n\}$ in ball $X$. Note that we do not know the subset $\{x_n\}$ is finite or countably infinite, but the infinite case includes the finite case. We will assume that $\{x_n\}$ is countably infinite.

Now define a function $d:\text{ball $X^*$}\times\text{ball $X^*$}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by $d(x^*,y^*)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x^*-y^*\rangle|}{2^n}$. 
For any $x^*,y^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$, we have $d(x^*,y^*)\geqslant0$ and $d(x^*,y^*)=d(y^*,x^*)$. 
Let $x^*,y^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$ be such that $x^*=y^*$. Then $d(x^*,y^*)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,0\rangle|}{2^n}=0$. Now let $d(x^*,y^*)=0$ for some $x^*,y^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$. Then $d(x^*,y^*)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x^*-y^*\rangle|}{2^n}=0$. Thus $|\langle x_n,x^*-y^*\rangle|=0$ for each $n$. It follows that $\langle x_n,x^*\rangle=\langle x_n,y^*\rangle$ for each $n$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is a dense subset of $\text{ball $X$}$, by Fact 2, $\langle x,x^*\rangle=\langle x,y^*\rangle$ for all $x\in \text{ball X}$ and hence for all $x\in X$. Thus $x^*=y^*$. Hence, for any $x^*,y^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$, $d(x^*,y^*)=0$ if and only if $x^*=y^*$. 
For any $x^*,y^*,z^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$,
\begin{align*}
 d(x^*,y^*)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x^*-y^*\rangle|}{2^n}\\&\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x^*-z^*\rangle|+|\langle x_n,z^*-y^*\rangle|}{2^n}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x^*-z^*\rangle|}{2^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,y^*-z^*\rangle|}{2^n}=d(x^*,z^*)+d(z^*,y^*).
 \end{align*}
Therefore, $d$ is a metric on ball $X^*$.

Now $(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$ is a metric space and it is metrizable. Let $wk^*$ be the weak-star topology on $\text{ball $X^*$}$. Let $I$ be the identity map from $(\text{ball $X^*$},wk^*)$ onto $(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$. To show ball $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable, we only have to show $I$ is a homeomorphism from $(\text{ball $X^*$},wk^*)$ onto $(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$. By Alaoglu's Theorem, $\text{ball $X^*$}$ is weak-star compact. Since $I$ is a bijection from a compact space onto a Hausdorff space, by Fact 3, we only need to show $I:(\text{ball $X^*$},wk^*)\rightarrow(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$ is continuous. Let $x^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}$ and let $(x_\alpha^*)_{\alpha\in A}$ be a net in $\text{ball $X^*$}$ such that $x_\alpha^*\overset{wk^*}{\longrightarrow} x^*$. Then $\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*\rangle\rightarrow\langle x_n,x^*\rangle$ for all $n$; that is, $\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle\rightarrow0$ for all $n$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is a subset of $\text{ball $X$}$, $|\langle x_n,x^*\rangle|\leqslant1$ and $|\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*\rangle|\leqslant1$ for all $n$.
For each $n$, we have $$\frac{|\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle|}{2^n}\leqslant\frac{|\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*\rangle|+|\langle x_n,x^*\rangle|}{2^n}\leqslant\frac{2}{2^n}=2^{1-n}.$$ For any given $\epsilon>0$, let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $2^{1-N}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle\rightarrow0$ for all $n$, for each $n\in\{1,\cdots, N\}$, there exists $\alpha_n\in A$ such that $\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle<\frac{2^n\epsilon}{2N}$ whenever $\alpha\succcurlyeq\alpha_n$. Taking $\alpha_0\succcurlyeq\alpha_1,\cdots$, $\alpha_N$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
 d(x^*,x_\alpha^*)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle|}{2^n}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{|\langle x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle|}{2^n}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{|\langle
 x_n,x_\alpha^*-x^*\rangle|}{2^n}\\&<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\epsilon}{2N}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}2^{1-n}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+2^{1-N}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon
 \end{align*}
whenever $\alpha\succcurlyeq\alpha_0$. Thus $x_\alpha^*\rightarrow x^*$ in $(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$. Hence, $I(x_\alpha^*)\rightarrow I(x^*)$. So, $I:(\text{ball $X^*$},wk^*)\rightarrow(\text{ball $X^*$},d)$ is continuous. Therefore, ball $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable.

Conversely, suppose ball $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable. Then there exists a metric $d$ on ball $X^*$ such that the weak-star topology on ball $X^*$ is induced by $d$. Let $$U_n=\{x^*\in\text{ball $X^*$}:d(x^*,0)<\frac{1}{n}\}\text{ for each } n\geqslant1.$$
Then for each $n\geqslant1$, $U_n$ is open in (ball $X^*$, $wk^*$) such that $0\in U_n$ and $\bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}U_n=\{0\}$. By the definition of the weak-star topology on ball $X^*$, there exist $x_{n_i}\in X$ and $\epsilon_{n_i}$ ($i=1,\cdots$, $m$) such that $$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{m}\{x^*\in\text{ball $X^*$},|\langle x_{n_i},x^*\rangle|<\epsilon_{n_i}\}\subseteq U_n\text{ for each $n$}.$$ For each $n$ and each $x^*\in\text{ball }X^*$, let $\epsilon_n=min\{\epsilon_{n_1},\cdots$, $\epsilon_{n_m}\}$ and let $|\langle x_{n},x^*\rangle|=\max\{|\langle x_{n_1},x^*\rangle|,\cdots$, $|\langle x_{n_m},x^*\rangle|\}$. Then $$\{x^*\in\text{ball }X^*:|\langle x_n,x^*\rangle|<\epsilon_n \}\subseteq U_n\text{ for each $n$}.$$ Let $F=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x_n\}$. Then $F$ is countable.

Now we claim that ${^\perp}(F^\perp)=\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$. Let $x\in F$ and let $x^*\in F^\perp$. Then by the definition of $^{\perp}(F^\perp)$, $\langle x,x^*\rangle=0$ and thus $x\in {^\perp}(F^\perp)$. Hence, $F\subseteq{^\perp}(F^\perp)$. Since $x^*$ is continuous for each $x^*\in F^\perp$, $\ker(x^*)$ is closed in $X$ for each $x^*\in F^\perp$. Since ${^\perp}(F^\perp)=\bigcap\limits_{x^*\in F^\perp}\ker(x^*)$, ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is closed in $X$. Since ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is a closed subspace of $X$, by the definition of the closed linear span, $\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)\subseteq{^\perp}(F^\perp)$. Now let $x_0\in {^\perp}(F^\perp)-\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$. Since $\{x_0\}$ and $\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$ are disjoint closed convex sets in $X$ with $\{x_0\}$ compact, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exist $f\in X^*$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\epsilon>0$ such that $$Re(f(x))\leqslant\alpha<\alpha+
\epsilon\leqslant Re(f(x_0))\text{ for all $x\in \overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$}.$$ Since $Re(f(\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)))$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, $Re(f(\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)))=\{0\}$. Thus $Re(f(x_0))\neq0$. So, $f(\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F))=0$ and $f(x_0)\neq0$. Since $F\subseteq\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$, $f(F)=0$; that is, $f\in F^\perp$. Since $x_0\in{^\perp}(F^\perp)$, $f(x_0)=0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, ${^\perp}(F^\perp)=\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$. Since $F$ is countable, by Fact 4, $\overline{\operatorname{span}}(F)$ is separable, and hence ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is separable by the claim above. Now we assume that $F^\perp\neq\{0\}$. Let $x^*\in F^\perp-\{0\}$. Then for each $n\geqslant1$, $|\langle x_n,\frac{x^*}{||x^*||}\rangle|=0<\epsilon_n$. Since $\frac{x^*}{||x^*||}\in\text{ball $X^*$}$, $\frac{x^*}{||x^*||}\in U_n$ for all $n\geqslant1$. Thus $\frac{x^*}{||x^*||}=0$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $F^\perp=\{0\}$. By the definition of ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$, we have ${^\perp}(F^\perp)=X$. Therefore, $X$ is separable.

Comment: I doubt anyone would be willing to read the whole thing. If you have problems with specific steps of the proof, you should extract them and ask specifically. As it stands, this is not fit for math.se -- I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Late to the party. I read the whole thing and I think your proof is fine. A shortcut in the $\Rightarrow$ direction might be to show that the identity map from $(X^*,\sigma(X,X^*))\to (X,d)$ is continuous.